# Insert a default UI row in Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, module

Right now, I have an app that inserts UI when clicking a button. In the default screen, only the button is visible. I have to click on the button to insert new rows.

I'm trying to display one row in the default screen.

This is what the default screen looks like:

[image]

But I want the default screen to look like this with one row inserted already:

[image]

I tried moving the `ui_placeholder` (s) to render in the main server but that didn't work.

Code for the app:

```
library(shiny)

newlist <- as.list(c("LV1", "LV2", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"))

symbol <- as.list(c("=~", "~"))

row_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    
    column(2,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder"))),
    column(2,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder3"))),
    
    column(2, 
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder2")))
  )
} 


row_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  return_value <- reactive({paste(input$variable1, input$symbol1, paste(input$variable2, collapse = "+"))})
  ns <- session$ns
  output$ui_placeholder <- renderUI({
    
    selectInput(ns("variable1"), "LV:", choices = c(' ', newlist), selected = NULL)
    
  })
  
  output$ui_placeholder2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("variable2"), "Ind:", choices = c(' ', names(HolzingerSwineford1939)), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$ui_placeholder3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("symbol1"), "Type", choices = c(' ', symbol), selected = NULL)
  })
  
  list(return_value = return_value) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(  
  div(id="placeholder"),
  actionButton("addLine", "+ LV"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out"),
  verbatimTextOutput("listout5")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  handler <- reactiveVal(list())
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    new_id <- paste("row", input$addLine, sep = "_")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = row_ui(new_id)
    )
    
    handler_list <- isolate(handler())
    new_handler <- callModule(row_server, new_id)
    handler_list <- c(handler_list, new_handler)
    names(handler_list)[length(handler_list)] <- new_id
    handler(handler_list)
  })
  
  outformula <- reactive({
    paste(sapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      paste0(handle(), collapse = " ")
    }), collapse="\n")
  })
  
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    cat(outformula())
  })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `callModule` and `insertUI` directly in the server function. This code gets only executed once on startup and shows you the first row.

I've made a few changes:

- I use `reactiveValues` instead of `reactiveVal`, especially if you deal with a list I find it easier
- however, the first added element (when I initialise the `reactiveValues`) is always the last element, so I need to do some extra logic to get the order right in `outformula`
- Because I directly use `reactiveValuesToList` with the `reactiveValues` object, I have to use `handle$return_value()` instead of `handle()` in `sapply` to get the changed structure of the reactives right.

```
library(shiny)

newlist <- as.list(c("LV1", "LV2", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"))

symbol <- as.list(c("=~", "~"))

HolzingerSwineford1939 <- c(a = 1,
                            b = 2,
                            c = 3)

row_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    
    column(2,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder"))),
    column(2,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder3"))),
    
    column(2, 
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder2")))
  )
} 


row_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  return_value <- reactive({paste(input$variable1, input$symbol1, paste(input$variable2, collapse = "+"))})
  ns <- session$ns
  output$ui_placeholder <- renderUI({
    
    selectInput(ns("variable1"), "LV:", choices = c(' ', newlist), selected = NULL)
    
  })
  
  output$ui_placeholder2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("variable2"), "Ind:", choices = c(' ', names(HolzingerSwineford1939)), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$ui_placeholder3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("symbol1"), "Type", choices = c(' ', symbol), selected = NULL)
  })
  
  list(return_value = return_value) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(  
  div(id="placeholder"),
  actionButton("addLine", "+ LV"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out"),
  verbatimTextOutput("listout5")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  handler <- reactiveValues(row_0 = callModule(row_server, "row_0"))
  insertUI(
    selector = "#placeholder",
    where = "beforeBegin",
    ui = row_ui("row_0")
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    new_id <- paste("row", input$addLine, sep = "_")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = row_ui(new_id)
    )
    
    handler[[new_id]] <- callModule(row_server, new_id)
  })
  
  outformula <- reactive({
    current_list <- reactiveValuesToList(handler)
    
    if (length(current_list) == 1) {
      correct_index <- 1
    } else {
      correct_index <- c(length(current_list), 1:(length(current_list) - 1))
    }
    paste(sapply(current_list[correct_index], function(handle) {
      paste0(handle$return_value(), collapse = " ")
    }), collapse="\n")
  })
  
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    cat(outformula())
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```